# Ajax is not working in php statement

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

getsubcat.php

```
<?php
include("config.php");
error_reporting(0);
 $checkedValue=$_GET['checkedValue']; 
$options= "";
$s=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `sub_category` INNER JOIN `category` on sub_category.cat_id=category.cat_id where category.cat_name='$checkedValue'");
         while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($s))
         {
             $subcategory=$rows['sub_cat_name'];

             echo '<input name="sub_category" type="checkbox" class="checkbox_check1" onclick="select_subcatinfo('.$subcategory.')" id="checkbox_check1'.$subcategory.'" value="'. $subcategory.'" >&nbsp;'.$subcategory.'<br /><br />';

         }

         ?>
```

This is my php coding which ll be loaded through ajax in another page.. Below is my ajax script.

Ajax Script

```
function select_subcatinfo(name)
{
    $("#wait").css("display","block");
    var checkedValue1 = name;
    if( $("#checkbox_check1"+name).is(':checked') ) 
    {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                $("#wait").css("display","none");
                data = xmlhttp.responseText.split("[BRK]");
                document.getElementById("DisplaySubcat").innerHTML = data[0]+" "+data[1];

            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getSubcatValue.php?checkedValue1="+checkedValue1,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    else
    {
        $("#wait").css("display","none");   
    }        
}
</script>
```

But inside that echo statement this function is not working.. any help here . thankss

Comment: Why are you using inline Javascript instead of just binding a single handler to the class using jQuery?

Comment: And why are you using that verbose AJAX syntax when you could be using `$.get()` or `$.ajax()`?

Comment: then how to do that ??

Comment: i m new to ajax so dnt knw its proper implementation.. @Barmar

Comment: Wowser...this is a train wreck... clean up your `getsubcat.php` ...no need for all the open/close tags. I won't even mention the ajax call

Comment: then how could i load that script @VIDesignz

Answer (score 3):

Don't use inline Javascript, use jQuery to bind the event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".checkbox_check1").click(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            $("#wait").show();
            $.get('getSubcatValue.php', { checkedValue1: this.value }, function(response) {
                var data = response.split('[BRK]');
                $("#DisplaySubcat").text(data[0] + ' ' + data[1]);
                $("#wait").hide();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: but that function is not working in the php echo statement ??

Comment: You don't use it in the PHP echo function. Use this instead.

Comment: just tell me how can i call my function inside that echo statement ??

Comment: i ve updated my ajax code wid ur 1.. but my doubt how can i call it in the getsubcat page so that my content ll be loaded

Comment: That's what this code does. It says that when you click on one of those elements, it will do the AJAX call. Make sure you put the code inside the `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: sorry for bothering u this much .. but i need this php coding to fetch value from database ??

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Can't you read my code? It fetches from the database using `$.get`.

Comment: You're not getting my answer. Sorry.

Comment: No this answer is perfect.. But the above php coding i m using to load sub_categories according to categories .. So when sum1 click 1 category accordingly the sub_categories ll get fetched n ll be printed in that echo statement.. but after that i want to do a sub_category wise search so if sum1 clicks from the sub_category , it should load the getSubcatValue.php page.. 
Thats it

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not trying to answer this...just cleaned up the op's PHP

```
<?php
require("config.php");
error_reporting(0);
$checkedValue = $_REQUEST['checkedValue']; 
$options = "";
$s=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `sub_category` INNER JOIN `category` on   sub_category.cat_id=category.cat_id where category.cat_name='$checkedValue'");
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($s))
    { 
        $subcategory=$rows['sub_cat_name'];
        echo '<div><input name="sub_category" type="checkbox" class="checkbox_check1" onclick="select_subcatinfo('.$subcategory.')" id="checkbox_check1'.$subcategory.'" value="'. $subcategory.'" >&nbsp;'.$subcategory.'<br /><br /></div>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: i ve already done that .. i just parted my codes with tags bcz of another reason

Comment: Unless you are separating functions or want to open/close phps tags for the sake of sanity, it just doesn't make sense to part them the way you did

Comment: chekc my editted code which is my actual codes.. as i said i ve parted my code for another reason ..